# Convert Wordpress Woocomerce product to Wordpress post

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

This question look like terrible :).

We have a shop with more than 10.000 product, but at this time we dont have bussiness and we want to convert woocomerce product into new database worpdress post to help server lighter and run faster.

Please tell me if anyway can convert Woocomerce Product to Wordpress post into new database.

We need only feature image, and prodcut content, tag, category.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can change WooCommerce products to normal posts with a post switcher plug-in like https://wordpress.org/plugins/convert-post-types/

Afterwards, you can disable the WooCommerce plug-in if you're looking to reduce the load of your website.

PS: I don't fully understand what you're trying to do, but I hope that helps!